# How to include view to component from another file in react native?

Tags: class, react-native, import, view, include

I have following classes how I can include View from another file like include() in php.

```
class A extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>A</Text> 
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class B extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>B</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class C extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>B</Text>    
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I have to include View from external file. we can include one class to another by just import but what about view?

Comment: can you be clear what you supposed to do? Do you want to show `component A` and `component B` in the third component? Or `Component A` inside `Component B`. What do you mean by `include`

Comment: all view inside component a,b,c would like to add in another file and include here like include() in php

Comment: I think `include` is similar to `import`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, a question you have is about importing file. 
Consider three things,

- **export**

  you can `export` **multiple** `const or class` and import them with `{}` in import statement.
- **export default**

  `export default` keyword used export `const` or `class` from file. The export default **is only for one file**.
- **import**

  import keyword used to import exported files, with file path followed by `from` keyword

  `import ExportWithDefault, {ExportWithOutDefault} from './fileName.js'`

References : [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), [export, export default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

let's consider Component `A,B,C` file `comps.js` exported as `export` only.
like

```
//file comp.js


 import React,{Component} from 'react'
 import {View, Text} from 'react-native'
   export class A extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>A</Text> 
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

export class B extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          
            B
          
        );
      }
    }

```
export class C extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>C</Text>    
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Now consider file `main.js` is a file where you want to import `A,B,C` and display.

```
import React, { Component} from 'react
import { View} from 'react-native
import {A,B,C} from './comp'; //considering both files in same directory
    class Main extends Component {
       render(){
         return(
         <View>
            <A/>
            <B/>
             <C/>
           </View>
         )
       }
    }
```

Comment: Error:Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function

Comment: I thought you already imported thing like `View and Text` in comp.js

Comment: view and text imported in comp.js and in main.js.. but without import error in both file. then how?

Comment: Its my mistake actually need to import View in both files we are using View in main.js. will update ans

Comment: We used `View` component but forgot to import and react returns single element